# Replace every input in form with its value property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am try to export html as pdf but I am not be able to export the form inputs fields so I need to replace form tag with its value.

I have one form that contain multiple labels and form inputs like text,checkbox,radio button,select etc.

I want to replace that input tag with its value property but I don't know How to do it..

ie.

```
<div id="Content">
    Name  : <input type="text" value="abc"/>
    Hobby : <input type="checkbox" value="abc" checked/>
            <input type="checkbox" value="abc"/>
    City  :<select class="form-control" id="EmployeeId" name="EmployeeId">
             <option value="">--Select One--</option>
             <option value="2454">Abc</option>
             <option value="2454">Def</option>
             <option value="2454" selected>Gif</option>
           </select>
</div>
```

if I have above html of this div than I want output like this

```
Name : abc
Hobby : abc
City  : Gif
```

Comment: `$(":input").each(function(){ $(this).replaceWith(this.value) })`

Comment: I have store this html in one variable like var x=$('#content'); than How to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/), *Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided new content*

[`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) Selects all `input`, `textarea`, `select` and `button` elements.

To show output in another `element`, clone the `target` element and do the manipulations on cloned(`clone()`) element.

```js
$('#preview').on('click', function() {
  var temp = $("#Content").clone(true);
  $("#target").append(temp);
  temp.find(":input").each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(this.value);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Content">
  Name :
  <input type="text" value="abc" />
  <br>Hobby :
  <input type="checkbox" value="abc" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="abc" />
  <br>City :
  <select class="form-control" id="EmployeeId" name="EmployeeId">
    <option value="">--Select One--</option>
    <option value="2454">Abc</option>
    <option value="2454">Def</option>
    <option value="2454" selected>Gif</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br>
<button id='preview'>Show Preview</button>
<h5>Target Elem</h5>
<div id='target'></div>
```

**Edit:** To apply conditions for `check-box`, Use `ternary` like this: `$(this).replaceWith(this.type == 'checkbox' ? (this.checked ? this.value : "") : this.value);`

Comment: I am not sure, but this code is generating error. http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/210/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi, That is fine :)

Comment: Do add `jQuery` library.. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/413cpuy1/1/

Comment: its give me a value of non selected checkbox also

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all the elements and then using .after() , place the new elements after the particular input. Then remove the current input element.

```
$("#replace").click(function() {
  $(":input").each(function() {
    $(this).after($(this).val());
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3515/)